# How to convert a numeric number into string?

Tags: smarty

I need to test if two variables are equals. But one is in string format and the other is a number.

So, I try to convert the variable in text, but without success.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Can you show some code? Have you tried the comparison? Chances are that if Smarty compares the same way as PHP's `==` does, `1` and `"1"` will turn out equal.

Comment: yes, I have tried to compare with ==, but it not works

Answer (score 2):

Try using {$number|string_format:"%.2f"} to convert both numbers to strings and compare them.
or {$number|string_format:"%d"} if it are integer, instead of float numbers.

I don't see a way in smarty to explicitly cast a sting to an integer, so you should convert both to a string.

If it doesn't work, please post your code. Maybe the issue lies in a different line..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem due to the php auto converting array keys (string) to integers based on the fact that they look like integers (this is actually a documented "feature"!) and then messing up my comparison in Smarty. The straight forward and quite an awful way to do it is:

```
{php}$this->assign('STR', strval($this->get_template_vars('NUM')));{/php}
```

If you need to use it more often in your code, consider writing a custom Smarty {strval}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use settype to convert the integer to a string, then compare them...

```
$var1 = 10;
$var2 = "10";
{$converted = settype($var2, 'integer')}
```

OR

```
{$converted = settype($var1, 'string')}
```

That will give you vars of the same type.  The only reason to have the $converted variable is because the bool returned will appear on your page if it isn't assigned.